# Arduino mega R17 led blink continuously

Tags: arduino-mega

I have bought 10 Arduino Mega 2560 clones and all of them have the same problem. When I connect the to my PC I get a message that windows cannot recognize that device and the LED at the board in R17 blinks non stop. normally this led stops when the arduino is ready. Also in the Arduino IDE I don't see the port option enable.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers?

Comment: Yes because i have another arduino mega and a duemilanove and they work

Comment: Are they genuine Arduino?

Comment: No they are clones and the working one is also clone

Comment: You're on your own then. Who know what they might be doing... or even what they might *be*.

Comment: Do you know what the R17 led is for? so i can search for it?

Comment: I don't even know what an R17 LED *is*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35462/discussion-between-agis-soleas-and-majenko).

Comment: Nobody can help you. You have some unknown clone and we don't know what it is. Maybe start with editing your question to include exactly what it is you have bought. Only then can we begin to help you.

Comment: This is what i bought        https://www.hellasdigital.gr/electronics/boards/microcontrollers/atmega2560-16au-ch340g-mega-2560-r3-board-usb-cable-for-arduino/

Comment: You need to install CH340 drivers!

Comment: i have downloaded the drivers and also installed them but in the device manager i dont see it. Windows still sees the arduino as unrecognized

Comment: I think the LED you mean is the one marked L which is situated next to resistor R17 (if I can read it on that small image). That is connected to pin 13, and it blinks. It blinks when there is no sketch installed, and it blinks when the default Blink.ino sketch is installed. Either way it blinks until you tell it to do something else. The CH340 chips are next to useless. They kind of work sometimes if you're lucky. Then suddenly they will die out of the blue. They are not good.

Comment: The CH340 don't just die actually. Clones get bricked by the drivers. Plus Windows with it's drivers has always been bad. All my Nanos that have the same chips have been working just fine like two years already but under a linux distro always.

Comment: Majenko you are correct for the L i didnt see that and i thought it was the R17 resistor. So if i manage to make it work and upload a sketch to it and power it via DC power supply one day will it stop working or if i make a lot of sketch uploads? I want them in order to have 4-5 sensors on them and some push buttons in order to do basic functions

Comment: Once the sketch is uploaded the CH340 is not required. Therefore it should keep working. Making a lot of uploads is not a problem, unless you are talking about over 10,000 uploads.

Comment: The CH340 is very susceptible to static. They die. They are cheap, and many corners have been cut, including ESD protection and, most notably, drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You need CH340G drivers. CH340G is a chip that basically replaces the usual ATMega 8U2/16U2 that is used for USB to serial interface. As CH340 cannot be reprogrammed it means that you can't emulate other USB devices with your arduino for example a keyboard.

---

You can download the drivers [here](http://www.5v.ru/ch340g.htm).

Comment: i have downloaded them before and installed them. Also my concern is that the boot led is not stoping to flash even though  i power it from DC power supply and not USB.

Comment: Boot LED? There are three LEDs. The RX, the TX, power and the manual controlled one that blinks on reset and with certain code.

I am also 100% sure you have installed the drivers wrong if Device Manager can't detect the device.

Comment: i know the TX and RX leds also in the MEGA there are 2 more leds that blink when you boot it and when it boots the stay ON. In my version now i have one led flashing non stop.

Comment: also in the drivers installation process i got the message drivers installed correctly so i dont know why windows still not recognize it. I have Windows 10 64bit

Comment: The two more LEDs are power (ON) and LED (L). No boot LED; use the right terms that way people can understand you a bit better. Just a friendly reminder.

Have you rebooted your machine fully? Google how to do that as I don't have Windows, pressing restart won't do it.

Also what pops up if you disconnect and reconnect the Arduino to your PC, does a driver installation window pop up?

Comment: Sorry for wrong terms but i am new to the arduino world and i dont know a lot. yes i rebooted it now removed the battery for total reboot again nothing. Also what is that flashing led that blink non stop? next to it is another led that is on permanent. The TX and RX leds are not flasing at all and the are located above those leds that i told you

Comment: Usually unprogrammed Arduinos have a Blink sketch uploaded to them as default (just blinking a led). You have to upload something new to it for it to stop but Windows can't detect the CH340G chip, so I'd suggest you'd uninstall the drivers, unplug all Arduinos before and when the uninstall is completed, reboot the machine again. Now reinstall the drivers as it was told and reconnect the Arduino. Now open the "Searching for drivers" window and wait for it to complete, make sure you have internet connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35466/discussion-between-agis-soleas-and-avamander).

Comment: also i checked my other working arduino mega which has also the CH340G chip so the drivers are in my PC. :S

Comment: In device manager when i connect one of the faulty boards i see device descriptor request failed but when i connect the working one i see USB CH340 SERIAL(COM3)

Comment: @AgisSoleas Do not connect a single new CH340 based board. It might be that the driver is bricking them. Download an Ubuntu Live ISO and try Arduino IDE there to see if it's actually the drivers.